# check if a spefic object exists

Tags: python, django, object

I am checking if a certain id exists. i am checking it in a clean method.

When i type a "correct" (exists) number, it tells me `'int' object is not subscriptable`

When i type a wrong (not exists)number, it tells me `local variable 'result' referenced before assignment`

Reason is that I can not check an id(from the database)?

my code:

```
class IDForm(forms.Form):
    ID = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        id = self.cleaned_data['ID']
        try:
            result = pmod.RentalInventory.objects.get(id=id)
        except result.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Number")
        return self.cleaned_data['ID']
```

I made some changes: now when i type the correct number, it will pass. When I type a wrong number, it shows `RentalInventory matching query does not exist`.

```
def clean_email(self):
    result = pmod.RentalInventory.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['ID'])
    if result.count() < 1:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid number")
    return self.cleaned_data['ID']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `clean` method should [always](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#django.forms.Form.clean) return the full collection of cleaned data.
2. When number object doesn't exist in `try` section, the `result` is not set, so you can't use it in `exception` section.

So change your code to:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class IDForm(forms.Form):
    ID = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    def clean(self):
        id = self.cleaned_data['ID']
        try:
            result = pmod.RentalInventory.objects.get(id=id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Number")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: I gave me a new error:'module' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'

Comment: I update my answer, is your class model `pmod.RentalInventory`? i think you can also replace `ObjectDoesNotExist` with `pmod.RentalInventory.DoesNotExist`

Comment: I change pmod to pmod.RentalInventory.   Now it can raise Validationerror(when i type a wrong number) However, when i type a correct number it shows 'int' object is not subscriptable